# Android studio needs to be updated for Mac Monterey

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-monterey

I am trying to install Android Studio after upgrading Mac to `macOS Monterey Version 12.0 Beta`. But after the studio gets installed I get the below error stating that `Android Studio needs to get updated`.

I am really not sure from where i get update the Android studio as after clicking on `Ok` button studio gets terminated.

[image]

Comment: Is your mac running using the M1 chip?

Comment: The warning is about Python 2 (learn more directs to https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). The crash after you click OK is something else.

Comment: JB reopened this issue for IntelliJ, but it looks like it affects many of JB's IDEs:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271050

Comment: So what do we do about it? The linked bug says to adjust the Python interpreter in "Settings | Python Interpreter" but I don't see such a thing in Android Studio

Comment: You wait until JetBrains updates to use the latest Python and Google merges that change into Android Studio, which hopefully happens before Apple actually drops support for Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems here:

1. Android Studio uses Python 2, which Apple is committing to dropping in a future version of macOS. That's what the warning is saying, albeit in less technical terms. It's up to JetBrains to update their IDE to not require Python 2, then Google to merge this change into Android Studio. There's nothing you or I can do but hope that this gets done before whatever version of macOS that drops compatibility complete ships.
2. You're running into an unrelated bug in Android Studio causing it to crash.

Update: It looks like Python 2 will be removed from macOS 12.3, and that Google will have a version that doesn't require it shortly (it's already in testing, I think).

Update #2: *Update: as of 2021.3, all known usages of the deprecated Python interpreter are eliminated.* So JetBrains/Google's part is now done, too.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it doesn't update Android Studio itself. I believe you should download the latest version of it yourself. Link: [Android Studio 2021.1.1 Canary](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) (Note: Canary is known for preview builds, upgrade to a stable version in the future)

If it persists, then it might be a bug from Apple/Google I believe.

Comment: So.. I would say Canary is typically not latest version. Android Studio should release the fix if it's stable.