# macOS Monterey - Android Studio Startup Problem

Tags: android, macos, macos-monterey

After switching to macos Monterey version android studio gives the error in the photo. If anyone has any information on this, I would be very happy.

I'm wondering if it creates a problem in the application development process.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. I am downloading android studio hoping it will work after install. No problem with Visual Studio. IntelliJ IDEA just proposed me to update when a launched it. It is now updating. May be will work nice with macOS Monterey. A.KOTE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio needs to be updated for Mac Monterey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294422/android-studio-needs-to-be-updated-for-mac-monterey)